# jquery ui dialog shown on escape key press

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, dialog

I came across a weird situation. I have a page which has a Jquery ui dialog and once I click escape dialog closes. if I repeatedly press escape key dialog appears again and again. What might be the reason?

Comment: If you could post some code, that might help someone answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer in this forum. Pass this as an option when you make your dialog

'$("#blah").dialog({closeOnEscape: false});'